# I've created a live Ubuntu USB and resized partitions. What do I need to do to access and use those partitions?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ownership

I've created a live Ubuntu USB and resized partitions. What do I need to do to access and use those partitions?

Here's what `fdisk -l` gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 57.33 GiB, 61555605504 bytes, 120225792 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Glide    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE

Device        Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        64   7465119  7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2   7465120  16902303  9437184  4.5G EFI System
/dev/sda3  16904192  37875711 20971520   10G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  37875712 120225728 82350017 39.3G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: What do you want to use the partitions for?

Comment: I used my laptop "Disks" to format the USB, then the Ubuntu procedure to create a live drive.  Then, I think, cfdisk to adjust the partitions.  Pt 3 for project data, Pt 4 for Timeshift snapshots,  For two computers.  Then rebooted to insure that I had a viable live drive,

Comment: "Disks" shows the partitions, "Files" just shows /SDA1 as the mount point.  I assume that fdisk and/or cfdisk to label the partitions after which maybe the partitions will be visible and mountable.  I just haven't seen it.